# Can i do this (Loop in Loop)?

Tags: php, for-loop

How can i do something like this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $_SESSION['variable'] * $_SESSION['variable2']; $i++) {
    $listo[$i] = $preparado1[$i].
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $_SESSION['variable2']; $i++) {
        $preparadoex[$i];
    };
}
```

But doesnt work, i think this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $_SESSION['variable'] * $_SESSION['variable2']; $i++) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $_SESSION['variable2']; $i++) {
        $listo[$i] = $preparado1[$i].$preparadoex[$i];
    }
}
```

The script is simply, i have two classes the first have 2 numbers and the two have 3 numbers i should "connect" all numbers (2) in the first class with all the numbers of the second class:

F-S
1-1,
1-2,
1-3,
2-1,
2-2,
2-3

Thanks

Comment: You can do this, but you will need to use a different variable for the inner loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use a different variable name to increment the second 'for' loop.

```
for($i = 1;$i <=$_SESSION['variable'] * $_SESSION['variable2']; $i++ )
{
    for($j = 1; $j <=$_SESSION['variable2']; $j++) 
    {
         $listo[] = $preparado1[$i] . $preparadoex[$j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You're re-defining `$i` inside of the second loop, which conflicts with the first loop's counter. Use another variable, like `$j`:

```
for($i = 1;$i <=$_SESSION['variable'] * $_SESSION['variable2']; $i++ ){
    for($j = 1; $j <=$_SESSION['variable2']; $j++){
         $listo[] = $preparado1[$i] . $preparadoex[$j];
    }
}
```

Comment: probably: $listo[$x++] = $preparado1[$i] . $preparadoex[$j];

Comment: Not seeing `$x` defined anywhere, but I think omitting that variable works too, as it appends it to the end of the list.

Comment: That's right, $x is not absolutely necessary. I was hoping that its declaration would be implied.

Comment: So, $listo[$x++] = $preparado1[$i] . $preparadoex[$j]; is correct?

Comment: Since `$x` is undefined, it's zero. Each time you call it, it increments by one, which references the end of the array. It's correct, and so is leaving `$x++` out completely, as that adds the element to the end of the array also.

Comment: Give me that :S
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /var/www/okse/proceso.php on line 29

Comment: How big are the two loops? That error means that PHP is taking too long to run your code. To overcome this (I suggest finding the problem first), try making your time limit higher: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Answer (score 3):

You can have multiple nested loop, not just two. The only thing you have to make sure is that they each use a unique loop counter.

```
for($i = 1;$i <=$_SESSION['variable'] * $_SESSION['variable2']; $i++ ){
    for($j = 1; $j <=$_SESSION['variable2']; $j++){
         $listo[$i] = $preparado1[$i] . $preparadoex[$i];
    }
}
```

In your test case your second for should use another variable like `$j`.